# correct implementation of custom cartalyst theme to laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using Cartalyst Platform/ Cartalyst theme for my new project and basically I have a problem with implementing it

How do you implement proper structure of cartalyst custom theme in laravel 5 and how do you call the view from the route/controller

I want to create a custom theme using cartalyst

here is my structure

```
public
   themes
     mytheme
        backend
           assets
           views
              layouts
                 master.blade.php
              partials
                 header.blade.php
              dashboard.blade.php
              somepage.blade.php
```

when I access the admin it still uses the default admin

Answer (score 0):

Platform themes have the directory structure separated first by frontend/backend then by your custom theme directory. So, you will need to swap **backend** with **mytheme** in your example.

```
public
   themes
      backend
         mytheme
           assets
           views
```